# Is it better to have several TextView in a layout or one TextView using spans?

Tags: android, layout, textview, spannablestring

This is a question I have been asking me a lot:

I got different types of information to display, each having a label and a data `TextView` - some of them are always visible, others (label + text) have to appear depending upon the data.

Now, which solution is easier (faster) to handle for Android and its layout system:

a) Combining a lot of `TextView`s in a `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout`, setting static information, font color, content for each of them individually

or

b) Using just ONE `TextView` and fitting the data into one String, using `TextSpan`s to provide information about color or even Typeface within the one `SpannableString` which is then displayed using my only one `TextView`.

I am not sure what is the key factor here - number of Objects, the time to measure the `TextView` content if it consists of rather complicated formatting?
How would you measure this?

In my concrete case, I am talking about a `ListView` item (so it is going to be on screen up to 10 times) consisting of 3 informations, meaning 3 label `TextView`s and 3 content `TextView`s in one row using a `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: I'd create a compound view, e.g. LabelTextView, which consists of a label and a textview...

Comment: @ElDuderino: can you explain why you would do that? Is that in relation to my question - in terms that it's faster that way or just out of convenience?

Comment: It is faster and it is more convenient. You will have a view which fits your needs, which you can style as you wish...if it is about the view. If it is about the text and styling it you will have to use Spans...

Comment: If it is compound, it includes both objects, the two TextViews... thus, I doubt it can get any faster, why would it?

Comment: Faster for you to set up, to save time... everything else is premature optimization...and can be tested by yourself in 5 min btw.